# why my bash shell session is exiting unexpectedly

Tags: bash

I am using putty to ssh into my Linux server. After I login using bash and I enter this command `exec echo abc` this causes my session to close. what is the reason for the session to close this way?

Answer (score 1):

`exec` tells the shell *to replace itself in memory* with the program being executed. Consequently, the shell is no longer running after a successful `exec`.

If you want your shell back afterwards, the command needs to be

```
echo abc
```

*not*

```
exec echo abc
```

Comment: (Community wiki to avoid harvesting rep from answering a known dupe)